# How do I make a CSS card split 50-50 for content and image?

Tags: html, css

Trying to make a responsive card with an image as its top 50% and the text/content area as the bottom 50%. I've tried a lot of properties but nothing seems to work.

```css
.container{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}

.container .image{
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 50%;
}

img{ 
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

.container .content{
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

h3{color: #494949;}
p{color: #8F8F8F}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='image'>
  <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/beautiful-nature-norway-aerial-photography-picture-id840781672?s=612x612" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
      <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, quidem?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Somehow managed to get the text/content area above but the image won't move unless I modify It's height. If I modify the height then the image doesn't fit a 100% in the container.

Comment: But... what if the text is too long?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

css grid can do this. Resize the screen until the text wrap to notice that the image follow the height of the content:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-grid; /* or grid based on your need */
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; /* equal height row */
  overflow: auto;
}

img {
  height: 0; /* let the text define the height (remove this if you want the iamge to define the size) */
  min-height: 100%; /* get 100% height defined by the text */
  width: 100%; /* cover all the container width */
  object-fit: cover;
}

.container .content {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

h3 {
  color: #494949;
}

p {
  color: #8F8F8F
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='image'>
    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/beautiful-nature-norway-aerial-photography-picture-id840781672?s=612x612" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim, quidem?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass remove height:0 from my code and it's done